# html button to change images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website in which I am currently periodically changing images, however, I would now like to also have the ability to change them by pressing a button. Usually this would be pretty easy, but for some reason the result is that it just makes the images appear below each other (which stretches the page up and down).

Another issue is that I want my images to first fade unto the screen (fade css function) and then fadeOut (fade off the screen) after their time is up. This should happen on regular rotations (so not when a person presses a button). I have no idea where to even start with this, but the animation does work.

Another thing is that, I haven't posted much here yet so I probably did something wrong (done that before here...). Any help is appreciated and I hope that I had provided enough code and info on the problem. If that isn't the case, then I will attempt to give any extra information as fast as I can, although I cannot send/show images as they are private.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();
var j = 0;

function chngImg(z) {
  j = z
}

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = j; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = j; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
```

```css
div.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grey {
  background: rgb(204, 203, 203);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 1.5s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .7
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .7
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/00.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">img1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/01.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">img2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/02.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">img3</div>
  </div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <button onclick="chngImg(0)"><span class="dot"></span> </button>
  <button onclick="chngImgo(1)"><span class="dot"></span> </button>
  <button onclick="chngImg(2)"><span class="dot"></span> </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use pictures from placeholder.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :
Just change the Pictures ;)

```js
var slideNum = 0;
showSlides();
var slides,dots;

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    slides = document.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");
    dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideNum++;
    if (slideNum> slides.length) {slideNum = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideNum-1].style.display = "flex";  
    dots[slideNum-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); 
}


function currentSlide(num) {
    if (num> slides.length) {num = 1}
    else if(num<1){num = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[num-1].style.display = "flex";  
    dots[num-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.fade img{
  width:100%;
}
    div.content {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }
    .box{
      margin: auto;
      width: 80%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
     
    .grey{
      background:rgb(204, 203, 203);
    }
    
    * {box-sizing: border-box;}
    body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
    .mySlides {display: none;}
    img {vertical-align: middle;}
    
    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    /* Caption text */
    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 75%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 1.5s ease;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    
    /* Fading animation */
    .fade {
        -webkit-animation-name: fade;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-name: fade;
        animation-duration: 5s;
    }
    .fadeOut {
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-name: fadeOut;
        animation-duration: 5s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .7} 
      to {opacity: 1}
    }
    
    @keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .7} 
      to {opacity: 1}
    }
    
    .fade-out {
      animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
      -webkit-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
    }
    @keyframes fadeOut {
      0% {
        opacity:1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity:0.7;
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
      0% {
        opacity:1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity:0.7;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">img1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">img2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                <img src="https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">img3</div>
    </div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <button onclick="currentSlide(1)"><span class="dot"></span> </button>
    <button onclick="currentSlide(2)"><span class="dot"></span> </button>
    <button onclick="currentSlide(3)"><span class="dot"></span> </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works really well, but in the case of being on the third image and then pressing the button to get to the second one, it will skip the third when the next rotation comes and go straight to the first one. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, this solution breaks image resizing on mobile/smaller screens (stretches the image height).

Comment: for your first point, I believe its better to add pause/play (button or click on slide) and for your second point, you need to add media queries to your Css File. if you want to do this, keep me informed. :)

Comment: Well, I found a fix about 10 minutes ago. Thank you very much, your solution is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Nice coding - could be better.
Anyway, modify

```
<button onclick="chngImg(0)">
```

to

```
<button onclick="chngImg(0);showSlides()">
```

and it should work...

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, this fixed the issue of putting the images at the right place, but a new issue arises as the images start changing really fast (faster the more times you press the button). Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Oh, right...  you have to also declare a global variable, say, `timeout` and use `timeout=setTimeout(...)` and clear it with `clearTimeout(timeout)` in the button.

Comment: This might work, but I already found a fix in the other answer, thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Good!  How about up-voting + thanks + selecting my answer - whatever/all you think?

Comment: I did upvote both of you, but the upvote is not visible because I don't have 15 upvotes yet... hahaha. I selected the other answer as correct, since he found the solution first. I guess I can select you too though. Nvm, I can only accept one. Sorry, but he was just faster.